# Does $AS=SB\iff f_A(\lambda)=f_B(\lambda)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Showing the converse is straightforward:
$$B=S^{-1}AS\Rightarrow f_B(\lambda)=\det(B-\lambda I_n)=\det(S^{-1}AS-\lambda I_n)=\det(S^{-1}(A-\lambda I_n)S)\\=(\det S)^{-1}\det (A-\lambda I_n)\det (S)=\big((\det S)^{-1}\det (S)\big)\det (A-\lambda I_n)=\det (A-\lambda I_n)=f_A(\lambda).$$

---

Is there a case where $f_A(\lambda)=f_B(\lambda)$ but $AS\neq SB$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Edit: To explain a little where this came from:  having the same characteristic polynomial means having the same eigenvalues with the same multiplicities.  If the eigenvalues are all distinct, then there's a basis of eigenvectors, so every matrix with that characteristic polynomial is similar to the matrix with the eigenvalues written down the diagonal.  However, if you have an eigenvalue with multiplicity $d>1$, that doesn't mean that the matrix fixes a subspace of dimension $d$ and acts as a scalar on that subspace; it can have the behavior of the second matrix I wrote.  If you want the complete explanation of this, look up Jordan Canonical Form.